# git remote in onedrive is not recognised

Tags: git

I have a project that is set up in git. I am trying to create a repository in onedrive but I can't get git to recognize the repo once it is created.

I created the folder in onedrive, removed an old origin, and added the new one. All this goes well until I try to query it or perform any action (eg a push) and I just get the 'Cannot read from remote repository' error. Please see the code.

the strange thing is that git quite happily creates the remote but then can't access it.

here is the process and the code

```
PS E:\ToolTrakka V7_git\tt> md   C:\users\rgudgeon.RGA\OneDrive\Development\tooltrakka_v7_repo.git


Directory: C:\users\rgudgeon.RGA\OneDrive\Development


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length   Name                                                                                
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                
d-----        30-Oct-16  10:08 AM                 tooltrakka_v7_repo.git                                                              



PS E:\ToolTrakka V7_git\tt> cd C:\users\rgudgeon.RGA\OneDrive\Development\tooltrakka_v7_repo.git

PS C:\users\rgudgeon.RGA\OneDrive\Development\tooltrakka_v7_repo.git> git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/rgudgeon.RGA/OneDrive/Development/tooltrakka_v7_repo.git/

PS C:\users\rgudgeon.RGA\OneDrive\Development\tooltrakka_v7_repo.git> cd "E:\ToolTrakka V7_git\tt"

PS E:\ToolTrakka V7_git\tt> git remote


PS E:\ToolTrakka V7_git\tt> git remote add origin file:\\\C:\users\rgudgeon.RGA\OneDrive\Development\tooltrakka_v7_repo.git

PS E:\ToolTrakka V7_git\tt> git remote
origin

E:\ToolTrakka V7_git\tt> git remote show origin
git : ssh: Could not resolve hostname file: Name or service not known
At line:1 char:1
+ git remote show origin
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ssh: Could not ...rvice not  known:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

PS E:\ToolTrakka V7_git\tt>  

PS E:\ToolTrakka V7_git\tt> git push -u origin master
git : ssh: Could not resolve hostname file: Name or service not known
At line:1 char:1
+ git push -u origin master
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ssh: Could not ...rvice not   known:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Does anyone have any ideas re this?

Regards Ray

Answer (score 1):

First, `git remote add name url` just adds the `(name, url)` pair to git config, there is no validation. So whatever you give to `git remote add`, it always happily creates the remote.

Second, `ssh: Could not resolve hostname file: Name or service not known` shows that git sees your origin as ssh protocol. Try changing `file:\\\` to `file:///`.

Comment: Thanks that appears to have fixed it. Sometimes it is the simplest things that trick one up.